# Finite-dimensional vector space isomorphism problem

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

So the question asks: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $T : V\to V$ be a linear transformation. Prove that if $T$ is surjective, then $T$ is an isomorphism. Show that the statement may be false if $V$ is not finite-dimensional.

So so far I got:

Since $T$ is surjective,  $\forall v_1\in V$, $\exists v_2\in V$ $: T(v_2) = v_1$.

$T$ carries linearly independent subsets of $V_1$ onto linearly independent subsets of $V_2$.

Assume that $T(x) = 0$.

If the set $\{x\}$ is linearly independent, then by assumption $\{0\}$ is linearly independent, which is a contradiction.

Hence, the set $\{x\}$ is linearly dependent.

Then $x = 0$. That is, $N(T) = \{0\}$. Therefore, $T$ is one-to-one.

Since $T$ is onto and one-to-one,

So $T$ is isomorphism.

But I think the proof will still hold if they are not finite -dimensional. Why is $T$ not isomorphism in that case?

Comment: For surjective part, it should be $T(v2) = v1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dimensions theorem: if $\;\dim V=n\;$ and $\;T:V\to V\;$ is a linear map, then

$$n=\dim\ker T+\dim\text{ Im }T$$

Thus, we get that

$$T\;\;\text{is surjective}\;\iff\dim\text{ Im }T=n\stackrel{\text{ by above}}\iff\dim\ker T=0$$

and thus $\;T\;$ is surjective iff it is injective iff it is bijective.

Now, let $\;V=\{\;\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset\Bbb R\}\;$ be the real linear space of all real sequences, with sum and scalar multiplication indexwise, and define

$$T:V\to V\;\;,\;\;\;\;T\{x_n\}:=\{x_2,x_3,....\}$$

Clearly $\;T\;$ is surjective but it is not injective.